# PgSQL - to_tsquery and JOINS leads to Error in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, arel

I have the following query:

```
query = param.tag_list.join("|")

title = "ts_headline(title, query) AS title" 
rank = "ts_rank_cd(tsv, query) AS rank"

Job.select(
  [
    title, rank, :starts_at, :slug, :job_position_id, :id, :city_id,
    :company_office_id
  ]
).from(
  "jobs, to_tsquery('english', '#{query}') AS query"
).where(
  "tsv @@ query AND enabled = true"
).with_position.with_city.with_office.order(
  "rank DESC, starts_at DESC"
).limit(limit)
```

The with_* scopes just do an includes on positions, city, office. Not more.

This leads to Arel making a query that produces an error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - PG::Error: ERROR:  invalid reference
>   to FROM-clause entry for table "jobs" LINE 1: ...ER JOIN
>   "job_positions" ON "job_positions"."id" = "jobs"."jo...
>                                                                ^ HINT:  There is an entry for table "jobs", but it cannot be referenced from
>   this part of the query.

This is most likely related to the problem of mixing implicit and explicit JOINS. See also this [ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297491/error-invalid-reference-to-from-clause)

The thing is that I don't know how to rewrite the query with the to_tsquery so that it works?

Muchas gracias in advance for any idea

**UPDATE**

Here the exact query that is produced by Arel in the end. The error refers to the jobs.job_position_id from the first LEFT OUTER JOIN

```
SELECT  
    ...
FROM 
    jobs, to_tsquery('english', 'coffeescript|backbone.js|javascript|node.js') AS query 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    "job_positions" ON "job_positions"."id" = "jobs"."job_position_id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    "cities" ON "cities"."id" = "jobs"."city_id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    "company_offices" ON "company_offices"."id" = "jobs"."company_office_id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    "companies" ON "companies"."id" = "company_offices"."company_id" 
WHERE 
    (tsv @@ query AND enabled = true) 
ORDER BY 
    rank DESC, starts_at DESC 
LIMIT 9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit hard to tell where the error is coming from exactly without the SQL you're actually generating, but you're almost certainly referencing jobs in a subquery that is at the same level as jobs in the query tree.

Basically, the construct that won't work is the following:

```
select ...
from foo, (select ... from bar where bar.x = foo.y) as baz
```

The easiest fix usually is to alias things accordingly:

```
select ...
from foo, (select ... from bar, foo as foo2 where bar.x = foo2.y and ...) as baz
```

See this question here for another example:

[SQL subquery questions, "ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323269/sql-subquery-questions-error-invalid-reference-to-from-clause-entry)

---

In your case, this:

```
FROM 
    jobs, to_tsquery('english', 'coffeescript|backbone.js|javascript|node.js') AS query 
WHERE 
    (tsv @@ query AND enabled = true)
```

Should be:

```
FROM 
    jobs
WHERE 
    (tsv @@ to_tsquery('english', 'coffeescript|backbone.js|javascript|node.js') AND enabled = true)
```

This should work too:

```
FROM 
    ( select to_tsquery('english', 'coffeescript|backbone.js|javascript|node.js') AS query ) q,
    jobs 
WHERE 
    (tsv @@ q.query AND enabled = true)
```

Comment: Can you try the transformed sql I suggested?